# Drop down terminal for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I have used Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 and there was a GNOME extension with which I could get a drop-down terminal like in some fps games...is there anything similar for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (not GNOME... the basic "unflavoured" Ubuntu OS)
[Screenshot Provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqMiN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **Guake** and **Tilda**. I personally use Guake in Ubuntu, and you can install it simply with:

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

There is also **Yakuake**, but it has a lot of KDE dependencies.

Comment: so if I install Kubuntu which is KDE based ( I think...) then I can go for Yakuake...?

Comment: Yes it will implement well then